# Objective C: Increase speed of REST calls on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, post

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 to do HTTP REST calls. For our application, it is crucial that the POST requests be as fast as possible.

After some testing, I observed that the REST POST takes around 5-6 seconds to succeed. If I make the POSTs occur at an interval of 2 seconds or so, this lag can be reduced to 3-4 seconds. Is this because the connection is kept open? There was another stackoverflow answer saying iOS closes the TCP connection after 3 seconds.

On the simulator, REST calls are completed much quicker. If the POSTS occur at an interval of 2 seconds, it takes only 1 second or less to succeed.

My question is: what are some strategies I can use to reduce the lag when REST calls are done on the iPhone?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The server is a raspberry pi, and all tests are done using a good WiFi connection.

Comment: So why is your POST taking that long to complete?  Is the payload size really large?  Is the server-side processing script not optimized? Are you operating on a slow cellular network?  There are any number of things that could make a POST "slow". Have you done any profiling to determine the probable culprit in your case?

Comment: @MikeBrant Payload is small. Just two small key value pairs. Network-wise, I'm using Wi-Fi network so that shouldn't be a problem. I do not think the problem lies with the server as the exact same POST is fast when done through the xcode simulator; it appears that the iPhone is somehow taking longer to send the POST. I'm gonna try running the POST on another thread to see how it goes.

Comment: Generally speaking, there's nothing inherently slow about iOS making POST requests.  My current application routinely makes 6-7 requests in under 1.5 seconds and most of that delay is attributable to the server.  We're going to need more information to be helpful.

Comment: @David What kind of information would be helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem! It was due to the raspberry pi server not having the latest HTTP/1.1 protocol. It was using 1.0. Also, keepalive was not enabled on the server side.